# Best Practice to parse email and collect information you need

Tags: c#, parsing, email, gmail

We have implemented algorithm to parse emails and collect information from it something like if the email is

```
Hi John,

Here is your reservation info  

    Name : John F 
    Date : 2/12/2013 
    State : NY ....
```

we save a configuration for each email form like Look for Keys like "Name", "Date", "State".. and those are our KEYS and ":" is a delimiter and anything the follows after ":" is a VALUE for that key. This is how we parse and collect info we wanted. We read the email from GMAIL inbox sometimes the Email body we get from GMAIL is cluttered and our algorithm can't read KEY:VALUE pairs and capture nothing. If you see the Actual email in GMAIL inbox it is neat and tidy with all the formatting and stuff but the Email source we get in the code is different. Not sure if this has to do anything with Encoding. Please suggest what could be the reason. Thanks

Really appreciate your thoughts.

[image]

Here is an example the first image is what we see in gmail and 2nd image is what we are getting as a source (plain text NOT HTML.) By the way we are parsing Plain text NOT HTML

Comment: Can you add an example?  Maybe a screenshot of the email and then a snippet of the text you're getting when you try to parse it?  Hard to say what it might be - encoding/html/?? without seeing what you're encountering.

Comment: Could you please show an example of such a "cluttered e-mail body"?

Comment: Is the 'cluttered' email HTML?